Panel/Taskbar disappeared when installing icon pack
When I was installing some icon-packs (from WhiteSur), I noticed that my panel/taskbar suddenly disappeared. I am using Kali Linux with I think XFCE.
If it may help when I run xfce-panel--preferences. It gives me an error.
"Failed to show the preferences dialog. GDBus.Error:org.freedesktopDBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name of org.xfce.Panel was not provided by any .service files.".
If this helps in any way I created .themes and .icons folders before all of this, the second I switched the the whitesur icon pack my taskbar dissapeared.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

(This answer was posted by the OP in the body of the question.)
This has been solved by running xfce-panel. The panel must have crashed. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1222401/how-to-fix-missing-panel-in-ubuntu-studio-19-10
